# variable not defined Google Console

Tags: javascript

I've use this code.

But in Google Console i get this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: stickers is not defined

The code is :

```
this.createSavedStickers = function(stickersJSON) {
  try {
    stickers = JSON.parse(stickersJSON);
  } catch (e) {
    for (var i in stickers) {
      sticker_properties = JSON.parse(stickers[i].properties);
      var from_left = this.calcLeft(sticker_properties.from_center);
      sticker = jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: stickers[i].sticker_id,
        class: 'wpst-sticker-note sticked saved',
        "data-from-center": sticker_properties.from_center,
        css: {
          "top": sticker_properties.top + "px",
          "left": from_left + "px",
          "position": "absolute"
        }
      }).appendTo('body');
      sticker.html(this.stickerHTML).find(".textarea").html(stickers[i].note);
      sticker.find(".resize").css({
        width: sticker_properties.width + "px",
        height: sticker_properties.height + "px"
      });
      this.bindEvents(sticker);
      this.allStickers.push(sticker);
    }
    console.log(e);

  }
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why is the code dealing with stickers in the catch block?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `stickers` in the `catch` block. If the one line in the `try` fails, `stickers` will indeed be undefined

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `var` to declare the variable:

```
var stickers = JSON.parse(stickersJSON);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `var` to declare a variable. Without `var` it will still declare it as a global, so that's not the problem.

Comment: While it is true that the OP should use `var stickers` to avoid the pollution of the global namespace, this would not solve the problem, it would just remove the error message. But the main problem is that the OP tries to iterate over the properties of `stickers` in the catch block, in this block `sticker` would be never be set.

Comment: Thanks ! now I get this error : VM2445:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token G in JSON at position 1542. How i see where is the mistake?

Comment: @emiliano, the error indicate invalid json. You can test the json string here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek you're right, but I agree with t.niese for the context of question.

Comment: Sorry, but OP what mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the catch block completely opposite to how it's supposed to be used.

`try` is where you put stuff that might throw an exception. But you hope it wont.

`catch` is where you put stuff you want to execute *if* an exception is thrown in the `try` block.

*You* are using `catch` like code you want to execute if nothing goes wrong.